# Cropping UIImage - change background color

Tags: ios, swift

I have a function that crops a UIImage to the dimensions of a given rectangle. Sometimes part of the rectangle falls outside the image. After cropping, the default color of this extra part is white. Is it possible to change this color?

```
func crop(mainImage:UIImage, rectangle:CGRect) -> UIImage?{

    let rectSize = CGSize(width: floor(rectangle.width), height: floor(rectangle.height))
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rectSize, false, mainImage.scale)
    let context:CGContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!;
    mainImage.draw(at: CGPoint(x: -rectangle.origin.x, y: -rectangle.origin.y))
    let croppedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return croppedImage
}
```

Comment: you can set the background color of uiimageview

Comment: @JaydeepVyas There is no UIImageView involved. I get the image from a capture session, crop a part of it and send it to a server.

Comment: Maybe that work should be done on server side. Unless it's a huge image, it should not take much data to send the whole picture. Then you'll have a consistent way to crop for all kind of device.

Comment: @RomOne The images are high resolution and would be taken frequently. Also, only the data inside the crop rectangle is of any value. Hence I am trying to do the cropping on the app side.

Comment: Maybe us a combination of `CGContext#setFillColor(CGColor)` and `CGContext#fill(CGRect)` before you draw the image

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use extension 
    extension UIImage {
        func crop( rect: CGRect) -> UIImage {
            var rect = rect
            rect.origin.x*=self.scale
            rect.origin.y*=self.scale
            rect.size.width*=self.scale
            rect.size.height*=self.scale

            let imageRef = self.cgImage!.cropping(to: rect)
            let image = UIImage(cgImage: imageRef!, scale: self.scale, orientation: self.imageOrientation)
            return image
        }
    }

either use method like below

/**
     Extracts image at a given rect from an image
     - parameter rect : rect for which UIImage should be extracted within
     - returns : new UIImage created from rect value supplied
     */
    func imageByCroppingAtRect(_ rect: CGRect) -> UIImage? {

        let imageRef: CGImage? = cgImage?.cropping(to: rect)
        if imageRef == nil {
            return nil
        } else {
            let subImage: UIImage = UIImage(cgImage: imageRef!)
            return subImage
        }
    }
```